# Implementar OnClick en un RecyclerView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Quiero implementar OnClick para que me lleve a un layout donde se amplíe la información en un RecyclerView en Android Studio, y por más que he buscado por internet soy incapaz de hacerlo funcionar en mi Adapter.

Os dejo por aquí el código a ver si sabéis como se puede solucionar, ya que yo lo doy por perdido. Por más que he conseguido implementarlo en otros adapter, en este no lo consigo, y tengo que utilizar este ya que es para un trabajo de DAM.

```
    public class ListaPersonasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaPersonasAdapter.PersonasViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuario;


    public ListaPersonasAdapter(ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuario) {
        this.listaUsuario = listaUsuario;
    }
    public interface  RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {

        void onClick(View v, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_personas,parent,false);
        return new PersonasViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.documento.setText(listaUsuario.get(position).getId().toString());
        holder.nombre.setText(listaUsuario.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.telefono.setText(listaUsuario.get(position).getTelefono());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuario.size();
    }


    public class PersonasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView documento,nombre,telefono;

        public PersonasViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            documento = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDocumento);
            nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
            telefono = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTelefono);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu interfaz no debería extender de la interfaz de onClickListener de Android para poder asignarla?

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar el evento click a cada item solo debes entrar a tu método `onBindViewHolder` y asignar el evento:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    //Tus acciones aqui...
});
```

Si el evento lo quieres asignar a un control en especifico por ejemplo un boton solo reemplazas el `itemView` por el nombre del boton.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes definida la interfaz en tu código:

```
  public interface  RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {

        void onClick(View v, int position);
  }
```

ahora en tu clase "holder"  implementa `OnClickListener` (el método `onClick()`):

```
public class PersonasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View
    .OnClickListener{

    TextView documento,nombre,telefono;

    public PersonasViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        documento = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDocumento);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
        telefono = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTelefono);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this); //Implementa onClick!

    }


     //Implementa onClick!
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        recyclerViewOnItemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
     }

}
```

Cuando definas el Adapter, define como parámetro la interfaz:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListaPersonasAdapter(listaUsuario, new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, int position) {

             //* Aquí realizaras tu acción de clic! :)

            }
        }));
```

Puedes revisar estos ejemplos :

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-RecyclerView-and-Fragment
https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Horizontal-ListView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]